# recursive and infinite ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I would like to create a possibly infinite tree of div.

This is what i'm actually doing :

```
<div ng-repeat="block in blocks">
    <p class="blocke" > {{block.title}} </p>
    <input class="childButton" ng-model="childName[$index]" type="text" placeholder="child name">
    <button class="childButton" ng-click="addChild($index)" >Add child to {{block.title}} </button>
</div>
```

but every block in blocks has an array of child blocks and so on.

I would like to create the same div as above for every existing block. At any level.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create custom directive which calls itself if there are child items. This, with some editing should work:

```
app.directive('block', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      block: '='
    },
    template: '<div>' +
      '<p class="blocke"> {{block.title}} </p>' +
      '<input class="childButton" ng-model="childName[$index]" type="text" placeholder="child name">' +
      '<button class="childButton" ng-click="addChild($index)" >Add child to {{block.title}} </button>' +
    '</div>',
    link: function($scope, $element) {
      if (angular.isArray($scope.block.childs) && $scope.block.childs.length > 0) {
        $element.append('<block ng-repeat="childBlocks in block.childs" block="childBlocks"></block>');
        $compile($element.contents().last())($scope);
      }
    }
  };
}]);
```

usage `<block ng-repeat="block in blocks" block="block></block>`

How it works: directive replaces your elements in views with directive template, then checks if there are some childs for block item, if so, appends block element (directive itself) and compiles it.

This particular code wasn't tested, but that's how I did in similar situation.

Comment: I aproximatively understand this directive but there is one problem. At least it is a problem for me. In the link function you test if $scope.block.childs is an array but what i do have is an array of blocks like this $scope.block=[{'title':'','childs':[]}] for instance. So i need to check $scope.block[index].childs. How do i do that, with which index?

Comment: You don't need indexes in this case. When using this directive with `ng-repeat="block in blocks"` you also pass current block item via `block="block"` attribute, so every time directive is called it is a different block in `$scope.block1` (first time it's block[0], then block[1] and so on.)

Comment: okay. but this $scope.block is never set... since we have block : '=' (i don't really know what that mean though) and then block="childBlock" which i assume is the array of blocks in every block but the first time the function is called $scope.childs is undefeined and thus i can't call $scope.block.childs

Comment: `$scope.block` is set by element attribute `block="block"`. `block: '='` is equivalent to `block: '=block'`, that means that `$scope.block` will have a value which is set in element attribute called `block` (mindblowing.. I know..). The first time this is called is from your view and if passed attribute has children, other directive is appended and child blocks are repeated and passed as `block`, so totally different scope is created where `block="childBlocks"` is equal to `$scope.block`

Comment: Everything seems to be working great except that the childblocks aren't displayed. The tree is built as i want but the only level displayed is the root level. The problem come from the fact that the function defined in 'link' is called only after a new block si created and not when a childblock is added